# Join on 3 tables not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get members according to business and subscriber id. But this is not working properly. Please help me to solve this.

```
SELECT distinct m.Fname,m.Created,m.[User_Name],b.Business_Name 
FROM dbo.Members m,dbo.Business b,dbo.Assign_Business a 
WHERE  m.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id 
AND  a.Business_id=b.id 
AND b.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id 
AND  a.Business_id='6' AND a.Subscriber_id='1'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply."a.Business_id='6' AND a.Subscriber_id='1'" part is not effected.after i change business id,it not retrive correct values

Comment: if you remove those conditions, is the output correct?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: seems not correct.when i remove conditions some values are display.if thnk "subcriber id =1".all the values which abelongs to subcriber id 1 are displayed.

Comment: http://sql-question.blogspot.in/2010/06/explain-sql-server-joins-with-examples.html try this link to solve your problem or atleast simplify the query

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
select distinct m.Fname,m.Created,m.[User_Name],b.Business_Name 
from dbo.Members m
left join dbo.Assign_Business a on m.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id
left join dbo.Business b on a.Business_id=b.id 
 where a.Business_id='6' and a.Subscriber_id='1' and  b.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First step, format your code cleanly. This will help greatly with debugging.

```
SELECT 
  distinct m.Fname,
           m.Created,
           m.[User_Name],
           b.Business_Name 
FROM 
  dbo.Members as M 
  inner join dbo.Assign_Business as A on M.Subscriber_Id = A.Subscriber_id
  inner join dbo.Business as B on B.id = A.Business_id and B.Subscriber_id = A.Subscriber_id 
WHERE
  A.Business_ID = '6'
  and A.Subscriber_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your tables' DDL but you can try

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       m.Fname,m.Created,m.[User_Name],b.Business_Name 
  FROM dbo.Business b INNER JOIN 
       dbo.Assign_Business a ON a.Business_id=b.id AND 
                                a.Subscriber_id=b.Subcriber_id INNER JOIN
       dbo.Members m ON m.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id
 WHERE a.Business_id=6 AND 
       a.Subscriber_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   m.Fname,
   m.Created,
   m.[User_Name],
   b.Business_Name 
FROM dbo.Members m
   INNER JOIN dbo.Assign_Business a ON m.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id
   INNER JOIN dbo.Business b ON a.Business_id=b.id AND b.Subcriber_id=a.Subscriber_id 
WHERE  
   a.Business_id='6' AND a.Subscriber_id='1'
```